# PHP Get variable value out of Object

Tags: php

I got following invalid code: (e.g. $column->Field == 'email')

```
echo $row[$column->Field];
```

With the Error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Thats the var_dump of *$row*:

```
object(stdClass)[17]
   public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
   public 'email' => string 'master' (length=9)
   public 'Name' => string 'THE MASTER' (length=28)
   public 'reply' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I now what the error means i just can'T figure out how to work around it (i Might be too tired)

Im looking for something like that: What is the correct/working way to do so?

```
echo $row->$column->Field;
```

---

IDK how i didnt got to that earlier but i just defined a variable before hand

```
$field = $column->Field
echo $row->$field;
```

Comment: if you want to do it in one line, try `$row->{$column->Field}`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `$row` is not an array (it is an object), yet you try to access it like an array (`$row[$column->Field]`). That is not possible, it is invalid code.

Comment: The rest of the question is inclear. What is `Field` meant to be? Do you mean that as a placeholder for on of the property names? You don't say so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So 2 Solutios to this one:

1) Define a Variable:

```
$field = $column->Field;
echo $row->$field;
```

2) Credit to Abdo Adel:

> If you want to do it in one line, try
>
> ```
> $row->{$column->Field}
> ```